# Is $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ uniformly continuous on $(1, \infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

is the function $f(x) = 1/x$ uniformly continuous on $(1, \infty)?$ I know that it is not uniformly continuous on $(0, \infty)$, but now I'm restricting it even more to get rid of most of the bad parts. I think the answer is yes.

Comment: It is. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Very roughly, "uniformly continuous" means "having bounded derivative".

Comment: Indeed, the function $f(x)=1/x$ will be uniformly continuous on any interval of the form $(\varepsilon,\infty)$ for any $\varepsilon>0$. The failure to be uniformly continuous only happens in a neighborhood of $0$, so if you prevent the variable from being able to get too close, you ensure uniform continuity (see Lord Shark the Unknown's comment, too).

Comment: Though as a caution on taking Lord Shark the Unknown's comment too literally - for example, $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $f(x) = x \sin(1/x)$ are both uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$ even though the derivative is unbounded in both cases.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown NO! Roughly, “having bounded derivative” is equivalent to being **Lipchitz**. Uniform continuity is a much weaker condition, as Daniel points out and can be made precise using holder or sobolev spaces for instance.

Comment: @Shalop That's why I said "**very** roughly".

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown there exist nowhere-differentiable functions on $[0,1]$ which are uniformly continuous. Even “very roughly” is simply inaccurate.

Comment: @Shalop And you'll find that these nowhere-differentiable functions are certainly very rough!

Comment: Ha (dry laughter)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x,y\in(1,\infty)$, then$$\left\lvert\frac1x-\frac1y\right\rvert=\frac{\lvert x-y\rvert}{xy}<\lvert x-y\rvert.$$So, for each $\varepsilon>0$, just take $\delta=\varepsilon$ and$$\lvert x-y\rvert<\delta\implies\left\lvert\frac1x-\frac1y\right\rvert<\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is differentiable at $(1,+\infty)$ and

$$|f'(x)|=|\frac{-1}{x^2}|\le 1$$

$$f' \text{ is bounded } \implies$$
$$f \text{ is Lipschitz} \implies$$
$$f \text{ is uniformly continuous}.$$